# Track the position of an element for a game

Tags: angular

I want to subscribe to the position of an element to check if a player lost, I provided Window in my **app.module.ts**

```
  providers: [
    {provide: Window, useValue: window}
  ]
```

I my component I added `constructor(private window: Window) {}`

And when I add to `ngAfterViewInit()`

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const topElement = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(this.myTrackedElement.nativeElement).getPropertyValue("top"))
    console.log(topElement)
  }
```

I am getting the right position, but I want to keep tracking it so I can check if the player lost.

Here is the component

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{
     title = 'first-game';
     @ViewChild("personnage", {read: ElementRef}) myTrackedElement: ElementRef;
     @ViewChild("ball", {read: ElementRef}) ball: ElementRef;
    
     public isStarted = false;
     public moveBall = false;
    
     constructor(private window: Window){}
    
    
     ngAfterViewInit() {
     const topElement = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(this.myTrackedElement.nativeElement).getPropertyValue("top"))
     console.log(topElement)
     } 
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

A ngAfterViewInit only is executed one time. You can has a Subject in a function

```
//create a service auxiliar
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PlayerService {
    constructor() { }
    position$:Subject<number>=new Subject<number>();
    sendPosition(element:ElementRef){
    const topElement = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(element.nativeElement)
                   .getPropertyValue("top"))
      position$.next(topElement)
    }
}
```

Then, each time your "player" move you call to the function sendPosition.

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{
   constructor(private playerService:PlayerService){}
   ngAfterViewInit(){
      this.playerService.position$.subscribe(res=>{
          console.log(res)
      }
      this.playerService.sendPosition(this.myTrackedElement);
   }
   //in another place
   move(){
      this.playerService.sendPosition(this.myTrackedElement);
   }
}
```

NOTE1: I use the ngAfterInit to subscribe to the subject, you can also subscribe in a ngOnInit.

NOTE2: I create a service, but if you has always the "player" you can create the observable in the own component.

Comment: I am so sorry I updated my post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66941118/change-detection-on-subscribe-to-element-position ! Thank you for your time !!